Moving line to previous line if meets condition
I have a file with various rows but in some cases my data breaks one row into two. I would like to move from this.
815    =   Other motor vehicle traffic accident involving collision on  the highway
816    =   Motor vehicle traffic accident due to loss of control, without collision on the 
817    =   Noncollision motor vehicle traffic
     accident while boarding or
    alighting

To this.
815    =   Other motor vehicle traffic accident involving collision on  the highway
816    =   Motor vehicle traffic accident due to loss of control, without collision on the 
817    =   Noncollision motor vehicle traffic accident while boarding or alighting

Any help welcome.

Have you looked at my answer? Does it work for you?


Ctrl+H
Find what: \R\h*(?!\d)
Replace with:   # a space
TICK Wrap around
SELECT Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(?!\d)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a digit after

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):

